# After retrive password, redirect to index page

Tags: redirect

I'm using wordpress 3,8.

When a user visit /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword and clicks "retrive password"

i would like do redirect them to /index.php instead of the login window.

Is it possible?

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lostpassword_redirect` filter:

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_redirect', 'wpse127373_lostpassword_redirect' );
function wpse127373_lostpassword_redirect() {
    return home_url();  // use the home URL for your site
}
```

Add this code to your active theme's `functions.php` file or -- if you want it to persists across theme changes -- add it to a [custom plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

#### References

- [Trac: `lostpassword_redirect` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-login.php#L505)
- [Codex: `home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)